# How do I replace the value against a key in a configuration file via phing build?

Tags: phing

When I run the build, I want to search for a config key `rollbackversion` in a config file and replace the value against it (`null`) with the current branch of the deployment server (prior to rollout). This is how I am storing the values -

```
destination = /home/sandeepan/mock_del_servers/box1
rollbackbranch = null
```

I already found ways to find and replace a value, but that is not what I am looking for. I want to specify a key and replace the value against it.

[find replace text in file with Phing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907398/find-replace-text-in-file-with-phing)

[How can I conditionally replace tokens in a config file with Capistrano or Phing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839081/how-can-i-conditionally-replace-tokens-in-a-config-file-with-capistrano-or-phing)

Answer (score -1):

I could not find any solution which is kind of more native to phing, but this regex which does the replacement, and put it in [phing's replaceregexp filter](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/ReplaceRegexp.html) -

```
<reflexive>
            <fileset dir="config/">
                <include pattern="generic.build.properties" />
            </fileset>
            <filterchain>
                <replaceregexp>
                    <regexp pattern="(rollbackbranch[\s]*=[\s]*)[a-z]*(\n)" replace="REPLACEMENT"/>
                </replaceregexp>
            </filterchain>
</reflexive>
```